# Unable to set the .SummaryRow property of the Outline class with VBA

Tags: vba, powerquery

having issues with a sheet that has a query table on it.  I want to group rows/columns based on hierarchy and the code below works on everything BUT the sheets with query tables (fed via Power Query).

Even with error handlers built in, the code seems to be avoiding them.

The code giving me fits is..
**    On Error Resume Next
With ws.Outline
.SummaryRow = xlAbove
End With
On Error GoTo 0**

```
    Sub update_default_row_column_groupings()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
 
    'Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
 
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("365 Day")

    On Error GoTo err_exit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To 8
        ws.Range("A1:A500").ClearOutline
        ws.Range("A1:Z1").ClearOutline
    Next i
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo err_exit

    'ws.Rows.Hidden = False
    'ws.Columns.Hidden = False

    ws.Cells.Columns("E:F").Group
    ws.Cells.Columns("I:J").Group
    ws.Cells.Columns("M").Group
    ws.Cells.Columns("Q:R").Group

    group_rows_hierarchy_level ws, hierarchy_level:="region", group_column:=1, start_row:=6
    group_rows_hierarchy_level ws, hierarchy_level:="division", group_column:=1, start_row:=5

err_exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
Sub group_rows_hierarchy_level(ByVal ws As Worksheet, hierarchy_level As String, group_column As Long, start_row As Long)
    'groups rows between instances of 'hierarchy_level' in 'group_column'

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim group_ranges As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set group_ranges = New Scripting.Dictionary

    last_row = ws.Cells(ws.Cells.Rows.Count, group_column).End(xlUp).Row

    group_start_row = 0
    group_end_row = 0

    For i = start_row To last_row

        previous_val = ws.Cells(i - 1, group_column).Value
        current_val = ws.Cells(i, group_column).Value

        If LCase(current_val) = LCase(hierarchy_level) Then
            If group_start_row = 0 Then
                group_start_row = i + 1
            ElseIf group_end_row = 0 Then
                If LCase(previous_val) = "division" And LCase(hierarchy_level) = "region" Then
                    group_end_row = i - 2
                Else
                    group_end_row = i - 1
                End If

                Rows("" & group_start_row & ":" & group_end_row).Group

                group_start_row = i + 1
                group_end_row = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ws.Rows("" & group_start_row & ":" & last_row).Group

    On Error Resume Next
    With ws.Outline
        .SummaryRow = xlAbove
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```